# How to load spring controller url in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to load the url in ajax based on that the spring controller do some process and returns the string value.after that i need to set the returned string value into my html label text.

i tied the following code

```
<script>

    function emailValidation(){

        var mail=$("#email").val();

        ajax: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/forgotPassword?email='+mail+'',{

            success:function(data) {
             $('#message').text(data); 
            }




    }

    </script>
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgotPassword", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String forgotPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String mail=request.getParameter("email");

    String status=userService.sendForgotEmailToUser(mail);

    //session.setAttribute("st", status);

    //model.addAttribute("ErrorMessage", status);

        return status;


    }
```

in the above code was not working can any one tell me how to achieve my need.

Comment: $.ajax({url: XX});

Comment: @rathna yeah it's working but data is not set to the message id

Comment: what happens when you hit the url directly in the browser? Does it invokes your Controller class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally got the answer i missed the @ResponseBody annotaion in controller class.After adding the annotation it working correctly.

changes i was mad in my code is shown bellow.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgotPassword", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String forgotPassword(Model m,HttpServletRequest request) {
        String mail=request.getParameter("email");

    String status=userService.sendForgotEmailToUser(mail);



        return status;


    }
```

**script function**

```
function emailValidation(){


        var mail=$("#email").val();



        $.ajax({
            url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/forgotPassword?email="+mail+"",  
            success:function(data) {

           $('#message').text(data); 
           }
          });

    }
```